# How to clear the value of an input if there is no results or if it has a null value?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to clear the value of an input depending if it finds or not an id, if it finds an existing id, js updates the value of an input, but if it doesn't it keeps the last one found but I need to have the value clear, can someone tell me what is wrong:

```
function driverdata(valueid)
{
    var numero_id = valueid;
    //console.log(valueid)
    var idselect = document.getElementById('driver'+id_number).value;
    document.getElementById("idinsearch"+ id_number).value = idselect;
    //console.log(idselect);
    var placa = document.getElementById("searchable"+idselect).value;
    console.log(placa);
    if (placa != null) {
        document.getElementById("placa"+ id_number).value = placa;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("placa"+ id_number).value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show full example with HTML? Because now if you pass `valueid` that does not exists (no element found) it will throw error when doing `var idselect = ...value`

Comment: Any specific reason you're using 3 different variables for the same content? `numero_id`, `valueid`, `id_number`?

Answer (score 1):

In the method driverdata you don't define variable `id_number` so it's undefined when you try get element by id

So if `id_number` is equal to the parameter of the method you can directly use it

moreover to clear value you are right it's elem.value = ""

withour yout html i can propose you the following one => your script run

```js
function driverdata(numberId)
{
    var idselect = document.getElementById('driver'+numberId).value;
    document.getElementById("idinsearch"+ numberId).value = idselect;
    var placa = document.getElementById("searchable"+idselect).value;
    if (placa != null) {
        document.getElementById("placa"+ numberId).value = placa;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("placa"+ numberId).value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="driverdata(1)">
click me<br/>
 driver<input id="driver1" value="1"/><br/>
  idinsearch<input id="idinsearch1"/><br/>
  <div id="searchable1">
    input that will be clear <input id="placa1" value="test"/>
  </div>
</div>
```